# How to keep fragment state?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I am new to fragment and Navigation Component. Now I am using Navigation component. I have two fragments.

A - Initial Screen
B - Some other screen

Now I am using following code to Navigate B

```
Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.B)
```

Then in B Screen, I am using following code to navigate A

```
Navigation.findNavController(it).popBackStack()
```

Now screen A onViewCreated is called. All UI is initial state how to I keep the UI state.

Thank you,

Comment: Use a combination of ViewModel and possibly onSaveInstanceState. Check https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: you can use ViewModel to preserve your state

Comment: i don't think it's normal way

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, or any new code you'd tried, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since someone has answered there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your information.